# Draw a line on top of uiwebview i.e. custom drawing on top of uiwebview

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, drawing

How can you draw a line on top of uiwebview?

On my app, when the user touches his finger on top of uiwebview and moves the finger (the underlying html content is plain text and not clickable), I want a line to be drawn.

Is this possible? Does Apple allow custom drawing on top of uiwebview?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `UIView` above the `UIWebView` with `frame` equal to the `UIWebView` and set its background color to `clearColor`. Then draw on it.